# reduce characters from LPWSTR and save it as LPCWSTR

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a string saved as LPWSTR.
I have to make a change in this string (reduce some characters) and save it as LPCWSTR.
How can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you mean by "save it as `LPCWSTR`"?  There should be no problem converting an `LPWSTR` to an `LPCWSTR`, but there are issues with copying data to a buffer/string that's pointed to by an `LPWCSTR`.

Answer (score 1):

An `LPWSTR` is just a pointer to an array of `WCHAR`s, which represent UTF-16 code units. Iterate through the characters, much like you would a `char *`, making the change you need. You might want to edit your post and explain exactly what change you need...

An `LPCWSTR` is just the const version of `LPWSTR`. (A `LPWSTR` is a `WCHAR *` and a `LPCWSTR` is a `const WCHAR *`.)

Answer (score 0):

An `LPWSTR` can be modified (no `C` in there). Just use `std::remove_if()` or any other function you'd like. You can then simply `const_cast<>` the pointer to a LPCWSTR.

Comment: You don't even need a const_cast -- you can *add* const to something implicitly; you only need a const_cast to *remove* the const qualifier.